# OpenNMS 24 installation in Debian Buster: unmet dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, snmp

Trying to install the last version of **OpenNMS** in the last stable version of **Debian**, following the [official installation instructions](https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/branches/develop/guide-install/guide-install.html) leads to an apt error with the repositories:

```
root@triplecero:~# apt update
Ign:1 http://nightly.odoo.com/12.0/nightly/deb ./ InRelease
Ign:2 https://debian.opennms.org stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://nightly.odoo.com/12.0/nightly/deb ./ Release
Hit:4 https://debian.opennms.org stable Release
Hit:7 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:9 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:12 http://linorg.usp.br/debian-marillat stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://debian.opennms.org stable Release (expected stable but got opennms-24)
root@triplecero:~#
```

That error can be fixed just changing the `stable` keyword in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opennms.list` repository file with `opennms-24`.

```
root@triplecero:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://nightly.odoo.com/12.0/nightly/deb ./ InRelease
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://nightly.odoo.com/12.0/nightly/deb ./ Release
Hit:9 http://linorg.usp.br/debian-marillat stable InRelease
Ign:10 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24 InRelease
Get:11 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24 Release [11.2 kB]
Get:12 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24 Release.gpg [224 B]
Get:13 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24/main Sources [3,696 B]
Get:14 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24/main i386 Packages [25.8 kB]
Get:15 https://debian.opennms.org opennms-24/main i386 Contents (deb) [97.6 kB]
Fetched 138 kB in 18s (7,643 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@triplecero:~#
```

But after that, I get dependency errors from apt when I'm trying to install **OpenNMS** (trying to install those packages leads to another dependency package errors).

```
root@triplecero:~# apt install opennms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opennms : Depends: opennms-server (= 24.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: opennms-webapp-jetty (= 24.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: opennms-source (= 24.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@triplecero:~#
```

Changing the repository from `opennms-24` to `opennms-23` or `opennms-22` leads to another unmet dependency errors with **PostgreSQL**.

Seems obvious the **Debian** **OpenNMS** repository has broken dependency packages. There's any other alternative to this or just have to wait to be fixed...?

Comment: Yes I did, after post this question I created an account in **OpenNMS Community** and post this very message. The issue was solved: [link](https://opennms.discourse.group/t/opennms-24-installation-in-debian-buster-unmet-dependencies/651).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought the apt error message was caused by an error in the OpenNMS repository: two deb packages with libraries needed, `jicmp` and `jicmp6`, weren't available in the repository for i386 architectures.

After reporting the [issue](https://opennms.discourse.group/t/opennms-24-installation-in-debian-buster-unmet-dependencies/651/10) the packages are now available and the `opennms` package can be installed fulfilling the dependencies.